# Parsing Data in horizontal_messages of set_validation_data

Tags: xcm, parachain-system

If I understand correctly, all cross-chain transfers in the destination network are fixed every block in the `parachainsystems.set_validation_date` extrinsic in `horizontal_messages` property.

Is there any way to parse this data into human form? Is there a description of the data structure?

For example, [here](https://karura.subscan.io/extrinsic/2253071-1) is **Karura** set_validation_date with not empty horizontal_messages from **Kintsugi** (paraId 2092):

```
"data":"000210010400010200b1200608000c00070010a5d4e80a1300010200b1200608000c00070010a5d4e8010700f2052a010d0100040001010042c37a8f52d17c05bd1f5f4d7b751daae60841b6554bdbc043dd5319fbc5c21b"
"sent_at":13514596
```

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal messages are a `BTreeMap<Paraid, Vec<InboundHrmpMessage>>`. You can find the [`InboundHrmpMessage`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/2c934ed2cddcbf39cc3d8575d086ce13d937ca95/core-primitives/src/lib.rs#L141) declaration here. The `data` field you then need to parse as versioned xcm message.